# How can I append the column values in multiple rows in into one row and combine multiple rows into one in python

Tags: python, merge, grouping

I have this data :

[image: Input Data]

I need the Output as follows :

[image: Output Data]

Basically I want to merge all the Risk Statements in to one on the basis of field ID1 and want to do it in python. Can someone please help me

Comment: Where is your input data, in xlsx or csv ?

Comment: The columns values are separated by a delimiter. Join them using the delimiter to combine all columns into rows.

Comment: the input data is a dataframe and i want the output as new dataframe